# background music not playing in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

When i run the code it play only the .wav file

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400), 0, 32)

pygame.mixer.music.load('background.ogg')
pygame.mixer.music.play()

soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound('bird.wav')
soundObj.play()
pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

someone know what i should do for the background.ogg to be played too?

Comment: Have you tried initialising the mixer before loading the music? And why are you stopping the music?

Comment: Thank you, very helpful ^^, the problem was the pygame.mixer.music.stop() i was stopping the music because the tutorial i'm reading stop it, but i think that i should use that command only after other codes, ty again ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

Basically, you're loading and playing the background noise, and then *immediately stopping it.* I also suggest you create a `main loop`, like so:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# This makes sure that you're not importing the module.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create surface
    size = width, height = (500, 400)
    # You don't need the extra arguments
    window = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    # Do sound stuff
    pygame.mixer.music.load('background.ogg')
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

    soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound('bird.wav')
    soundObj.play()
    # This is your main loop.
    running = True
    while running:
        # Check if escape was pressed
```

Most of the time people just check if `Escape` was pressed in their main loop (if it was pressed, they set `running = False` and exit the program).

Comment: Thank you for explaining me what i was doing wrong, i didn't really knew why the pygame.mixer.music.stop() stopped my background music immediately until you explained it, you explain really well ^^, also ty for the suggestion it will be very useful.

Comment: Thanks for posting a fuller explanation of the problem. I didn't have time to write more than my comment!