# Keydown while execution of a function

Tags: python, time, pygame

i have a function `sounds()` in Pygame that executes and plays sounds for around 10 seconds.
While these 10 seconds i want to be able to click on a button/keydown and meassure the time when press the key with a function called `keydown()`.

But it seems like that i cannot do that. with the code below. In my case it excecutes `sounds()` and don't let me make any keydowns while `sounds()` is executing. When i only call `keydown()` and mute `sounds()`, then it works with pushing keydowns but there are no sounds.

```
pygame.init()
time.sleep(10)
def sounds():
   #some action
   def keydown()...

sounds()
```

Comment: Did you make it work? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like maybe your call to play the sounds is blocking the code execution. You should be able to play sounds without blocking with

```
pygame.mixer.music.load('sound.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Then follow with your `keydown` method.

Comment: Maybe also have a look at the example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099556/background-music-not-playing-in-pygame)